# Proper view controller not displayed when tapping push notification

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have implemented push notifications and am attempting to take the user to another view controller (opposed to just opening the app) when they tap the notification. I was going off of the apple website example but have not had any luck yet.

It seems that it never even enters my code as it should. I tried putting an NSLog to prove that and I was right.

Does anyone know why? The view controller I want implemented is called statsViewController.

Thanks

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (remoteNotif) {      


    NSLog (@"We are here now");
    [self handleRemoteNotification:application userInfo:remoteNotif]; //custom method where View controller will be implemented
    return YES;
}

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}


-(void) handleRemoteNotification:(UIApplication *)application userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

statsViewController* viewController = [[statsViewController alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; //Don't think this is right since I never use it in didFinishLaunching... I simply just declared it delegate.h
[viewController release];

 }
```